# Modify lock object outside the critical section

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, locking

Suppose i have following code

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
lock(rect)
{
  ----
  ---
  ---
}
```

Can the rect object, or its properties be modified in some other thread, while one thread has acquired the lock, and executing in critical section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the rect object, or its properties be modified in some other
>   thread, while one thread has acquired the lock, and executing in
>   critical section.

If **all** code that accesses that object first attempts to acquire the same lock, then No.

Without the locking code wrapper, then yes another thread can (and at some point will) write to the `rect` with inconsistent results.